# Django inherited models foreign key clash

Tags: python, django-models

I am making a Q&A site like stackoverflow. But Django model field clashes.
I am using Django2.1.5

I tried to add `related_name = 'answers_case'` but nothing changed.

Here is my models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    body = models.TextField()
    last_edit_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Case(Post):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    keyword = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword)


class Answer(Post):
    case = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers_case')
    is_accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And the error is:

> Unhandled exception in thread started by .wrapper at 0x7fa57c42c7b8>
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/emre/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/emre/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
>       self.check(display_num_errors=True)
>     File "/home/emre/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 425, in check
>       raise SystemCheckError(msg)
>   django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:
>
> ERRORS:
>   medicus_website.Answer.case: (models.E006) The field 'case' clashes with the field 'case' from model 'medicus_website.post'.
>
> System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fell into a *trap* of models inheritance in django. You are applying the [Multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance), while I assume you are expecting the [Abstract inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes).

In other words, your `Post` already has a `case` field -  since you have multi-table inheritance from `Case` to `Post`, each `Post` might have corresponding `Case`, and that's why you have the name clash. If you want to maintain current behaviour (in terms of db structure and relations construction) you will have to rename either `Case` model or `case` field in answer. On the other hand, if you'd like to switch to abstract inheritance, with each table self-conatined, you could do this like this:

```
class AbstractPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    body = models.TextField()
    last_edit_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Post(AbstractPost):
    # if you need standalone posts
    pass


class Case(AbstractPost):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=150)
    view_count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    keyword = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword)

class Answer(Post):
    case = models.ForeignKey(Case, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='answers_case')
    is_accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Comment: Actually Post itself is a different table. Case and Answer is derived from Post with additional fields. And an Answer is dependent on a Case. I am not a django expert so just talking from database perspective.

Comment: Alright, somehow I managed to confuse the inheritance order in your example. I updated the answer.